# htaccess rewrite to nginx bugs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

i had this code in my old .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?page=([a-z0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

and I've recently upgraded to nginx and I got the following code to use in my config instead of the Apache rewrite rules.

```
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1$args? last;
```

This works fine too, but when I try and load my stylesheet in /Style/Main.css, it tries loading the file as a get request. How can I fix this so it doesn't do this?

Comment: Anybody? I still need an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `try_files` to check whether the requested url (in your case, it would be css, js, etc.) exists or not, before you pass it to the rewrite. Try something like:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1$args? last;
}
```